# WCF Security outside internal network

Tags: wcf, security, axapta, aif

Here is the scenario.  Two different networks.  We have client desktop applications on one network that needs to connect to network #2.  Network #2 has a WCF service running, that is accessible to our network publicly.  In turn that WCF service will pass information to our ERP app AX, which exposes a AIF service.
Now the issue is we need to use windows authentication because we need to authenticate users that use the AIF service.

How do we pass user credentials on network #1. to network #2 over HTTPS to authenticate against the web service, then in turn authenticate to the AIF.

I read this article but i don't know if it will work over two seperate networks. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36289/steps-to-enable-windows-authentication-on-WCF-Ba

any help would be nice thanks

Comment: Do you need to know what users on network #1 are sending the data?  Because if no, you can just have your #2 WCF service running/passing data as one authenticated user.

Comment: Are all systems in the same Active Directory domain or domains which are trusted (e.g. in the same forest) ? This is one of the most important questions here. Different network is no problem as long as all machines are reachable among themselves. Perhaps you mean "different domains" instead ? Are all machines use same DNS ?

Comment: alex - No we need to know which user is passing information through the web service into AX so it can't run as one authenticated user and @RainerSchaack , ya they are totally different networks.. two seperate companies operating on different network and domain. we can see eachothers AD accounts though, there is a trust there.

Comment: Ok, domain trust is good... I cannot provide a complete answer (I do not know about MS Dyn. ERP, sorry), but you should be aware of a few things: This seems like a "double hop scenario", which requires delegation. I just wrote an anwer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29029715/access-denied-when-reading-writing-to-network-location-as-a-remote-process, also see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389288%28VS.85%29.aspx.